# Filtering both Parent and Child Grids in Telerik hierarchical Grid

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-grid

Let's say I have a super basic implementation of the Telerik Hierarchy Grid for Blazor.

```
<TelerikGrid Data="salesTeamMembers">
    <GridToolBar>
        <GridSearchBox />
    </GridToolBar>

    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="Id"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="Name"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>

    <DetailTemplate>       
        @{
            var employee = context as MainModel;
            <TelerikGrid Data="employee.Orders" Pageable="true" PageSize="5">
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field="OrderId"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="OrderDetail"></GridColumn>
                </GridColumns>
            </TelerikGrid>
        }
    </DetailTemplate>
</TelerikGrid>

@code {
    List<MainModel> salesTeamMembers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        salesTeamMembers = GenerateData();
    }

    private List<MainModel> GenerateData()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<MainModel> data = new List<MainModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MainModel mdl = new MainModel { Id = i, Name = $"Name {i}" };
            mdl.Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, 15)
                                   .Select(x => new DetailsModel
                                       {
                                           OrderId = x,
                                           OrderDetail = $"Random detail {x ^ i}"
                                       }).ToList();
            data.Add(mdl);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public class MainModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<DetailsModel> Orders { get; set; } 
    }

    public class DetailsModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderDetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Would it be possible, using the `<GridSearchBox>` component, to be able to filter both the Parent and Child grids?

Using the example above, lets say I typed in "Random detail 1" into the search box. This would only filter the Parent Grid - retrieving no records. Is there any way I could implement this in which would allow me to filter for both grids?

**Edit**

The closest I have gotten is demonstrated in the updated code below.

```
<TelerikGrid Data="salesTeamMembers">
    <GridToolBar>
        <GridSearchBox />
    </GridToolBar>

    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="Id"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field="Name"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Width="1px" Field="OrderDetailCombined" Resizable="false">
            <Template>
                @{
                    var member = context as MainModel;                  

                    var combinedDetail = string.Join(", ", member.Orders.Select(x => x.OrderDetail));
                    
                    member.OrderDetailCombined = string.Join(",", combinedDetail);

                    if (member.OrderDetailCombined != null)
                    {
                        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">@member.OrderDetailCombined</span>
                    }
                }
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>

    <DetailTemplate>
        @{
            var employee = context as MainModel;
            <TelerikGrid Data="employee.Orders" Pageable="true" PageSize="5">
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field="OrderId"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="OrderDetail"></GridColumn>
                </GridColumns>
            </TelerikGrid>
        }
    </DetailTemplate>
</TelerikGrid>

@code {
    List<MainModel> salesTeamMembers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        salesTeamMembers = GenerateData();
    }

    private List<MainModel> GenerateData()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<MainModel> data = new List<MainModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MainModel mdl = new MainModel { Id = i, Name = $"Name {i}" };
            mdl.Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, 25)
                                   .Select(x => new DetailsModel
                                       {
                                           OrderId = x,
                                           OrderDetail = RandomString()
                                       }).ToList();
            data.Add(mdl);
        }
        return data;
    }

    public class MainModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<DetailsModel> Orders { get; set; }
        public string OrderDetailCombined { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailsModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderDetail { get; set; }
    }

    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static string RandomString()
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 6)
            .Select(s => s[rnd.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Basically, I decided to add a new string field in the MainModel: `public string OrderDetailCombined { get; set; }` and used the `string.Join()` method to "flatten" the data that I wanted to filter for.

Additionally, since I wouldn't want to display this new column, and since you can't filter on hidden fields, I made the column 1px wide so it would be hidden and still searchable.

I know this can't be the best approach. So, still wondering if anyone has a better approach?

I found this knowledge-base-article: [Filter both Parent and Child Grids in Hierarchy](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-filter-parent-and-child) from Telerik that shows how to do this in jQuery, but I'm not sure how to replicate that in Blazor.

Comment: Looks like you can set the search filter via code: https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/filter/searchbox#filter-from-code

Maybe make your own single textbox and use it to filter both grids programmatically

Comment: Or consider using a treelist for hierarchical data